# Proper way to use chain of promises with JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, deferred, fs

The task is the following. I need to delete folder and it's content using rmdir from [fs2](https://npmjs.org/package/fs2) library. It returns [deffered](https://npmjs.org/package/deferred) promise object. After it complete I need to create folder again. And function should return promise as well for further chaining.

The code I have right now is like this:

```
function clearOutputDir() {
    var def = deferred();
    var def2 = deferred();

    if (fs.existsSync(outputFolder)) {
        def.resolve(fs2.rmdir(outputFolder, {recursive: true, force: true}));
    } else {
        def.resolve();
    }

    def2.resolve(def.promise.then(function () {
        return deferred.promisify(fs.mkdir)(outputFolder);
    }));

    return def2.promise;
}
```

Looks like it works, but it's ugly as hell. Can it be done simpler without def and def2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, there's no need to create unresolved promises on your own, it's cleaner to work with those returned by fs2 functions and "then" them, Plynx solution is good hint in that case

Secondly, due to async nature of things (and of how file system functions internally works), you should not use *fs.exists* function, it's generally deprecated, and good idea is to not use it at all, but do what you want to do directly, and rely on eventual error codes.
See: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/nodejs/gRRuly79oRc it sheds more light on this.

Getting to the solution:
Instead of promisifing *fs.mkdir*, you can also use mkdir from fs2, as unless custom options are supplied it works exactly as (fallbacks to) *fs.mkdir*, and does what you want, returns promise.

```
function clearOutputDir(outputFolder) {
    return fs2.rmdir(outputFolder, { recursive: true, force: true }).then(null, function (e) {
         // Ignore "No such dir" error, otherwise propagate further
         if (e.code === 'ENOENT') return null;
         throw e;
     }).then(fs2.mkdir.bind(fs2, outputFolder));
}
```

*fs2.mkdir* will be run only if *fs2.rmdir* is succesful or dir didn't exist. I've used *bind* to pass it with *outputFolder*, it has same effect as:

```
function clearOutuputDir(outputFolder) {
    ...
    }).then(function () { return fs2.mkdir(outputFolder); });
}
```

If you decide to use *promisify*, it's always better to reuse promisified version, and do not create it on each function call:

```
var mkdir = deferred.promisify(fs.mkdir);
function clearOutputDir(outputFolder) {
    ...
   }).then(function () { return mkdir(outputFolder); });
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I like initial approach. The think the problem with my understanding was that .then returns promise. With that It's all become clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [final-fs](https://github.com/finalclass/final-fs) library for this purpose. Take a look at it's chaining example - it's very clean.

It uses [when](https://github.com/cujojs/when) library for it's async calls so it's almost impossible to fall into callback hell. Chaining is very easy - it's done by returning a Promise in a resolve function.

The code would look like that:

```
var ffs = require('final-fs');

/**
 * @param {string} outputDir
 * @returns {Promise}
 */
function clearOutputDir(outputDir) {
    return ffs.exists(outputDir)
        .then(function (exists) {
            if (exists) {
                return ffs.rmdirRecursive(outputDir);
            }
        })
        .then(function () {
            return ffs.mkdir(outputDir);
        });
}
```